# how to create a pseudorandom number generator program that acts as both a magic 8 ball and choosing a card out of a deck of cards?

Tags: python, spyder

As the title says, I want to know how one would create a pseudorandom number generator program that acts as both a magic 8 ball and picking a card out of a deck of cards. This is the code I currently have for the magic 8 ball:

```
response = ["As I see it, yes", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now", "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Don't count on it", "It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Most likely", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "Outlook good", "Reply hazy, try again", "Signs point to yes", "Very doubtful", "Without a doubt", "Yes", "Yes - definitely", "You may rely on it"]

import math

#Constants
N = 10000 # The norm
A = 4875  # The adder
M = 8601  # The multiplier

K = 1
# -----------------------------------------
# The pseudorandom number generator

keep_going = 'Y'

while keep_going in ['y', 'Y']: #Allows user to input either a lowercase or uppercase 'Y' when asked if they want to ask another question
    X = input("Enter a YES or NO question: ")
    S = int(input("Now enter an integer: "))
    for i in range(K):
        S = (S * M + A) % N # Random Number Generator
        r = S/N #On the interval [0,1)
        magic = math.floor(20 *r)
        print("The Magic 8 Ball says:", response[magic]) 

        #Asking the user if they want to ask another question
        keep_going = input('Do you want to ask another question ' +
                           '(Enter Y for yes and N for no): ')
```

What my idea is that if the user inputs "n", I want the program to then ask the user if they would like to pick random cards out of a deck of cards, and then instead of acting like the magic 8 ball program, it acts like a program that picks, for example, 5 random cards from the 52 possible options. Ideally, I would want the "card-picking program" to be in the same pseudorandom number generator layout.

Comment: `random.choice(<set of all possible 8-ball answers>)` & `random.choice(<set of all possible cards in a deck>)`

Comment: Your magic generator is too simple for humans to guess with K=1. And if you are hoping to increase the value of K or randomize it then your line 23 and 24 should be outside the for loop.

Comment: What is the problem with implementing your idea? Just pick 5 random items out of a list of 52 possibilities (do not forget to remove each after picking).